# Error 2908 for msi installer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, installation

During installation of the msi setup on Windows xp, if I select the "just me" option I am getting following errors:

> "Installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package . The error Code is 2908 ."

If I select the "everyone" option it gets installed but if I try to launch the application:

> the application has encountered a problem and needs to close

I first tried installing the application on the machine on which it is programmed and setup is created and has window 7 os and the installer and application works fine . Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error code 2908 means that the installer failed to register a component: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372835(VS.85).aspx

I recommend creating a verbose log of the install to see what component fails to register correctly: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2545723

Here is also information about what information a log can give you: http://blogs.technet.com/b/paulpaa/archive/2010/02/05/how-to-read-a-windows-installer-verbose-log.aspx